# Spring file download only locally and not on the server

Tags: java, linux

I was implementing the file download function with Spring, and there was a problem that I couldn't find the file on the server.

Two paths are used below, but the first path works locally, but the file cannot be found on the server. There seems to be a problem with the route, how should I set the route?

```
 /* "src/main/resources/static/resource/upload/ctgryItem.xlsx" */
 /*  resource/upload/ctgryItem.xlsx */

File file = new File(path);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
String outputFileName = new String(file.getName().getBytes("KSC5601"), "8859_1");
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + outputFileName + "\"");
        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

Enable Linux server tomcat

Two paths are used below, but the first path works locally, but the file cannot be found on the server. There seems to be a problem with the route, how should I set the route?

Comment: You could change the title to: resource file is not found in tomcat server or something like that, because this is not related to spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Quick answer

Since your app is packaged as jar or war, the **resources** folder don't exist. resources folder only exist at the development stage (eclipse / intellij)

## Solution

Check if the war is being packaged with the excel files inside of it:

- Just compile it `mvn clean package` and unzip the /target/foo.war
- Or deploy it to your tomcat and check the webapps/foo to see if your excel is somewhere

If the content of resources folder is not being packaged inside of the war, search a maven configuration to do that. By default is enabled that behavior.

If file exist inside of war, load it using the **Classloader**, not directly using java.io.File

- With pure spring

```
try {
    File file = 
    ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:upload/ctgryItem.xlsx")
    byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

- With pure Java

```
InputStream ioStream = Foo.getClass()
.getClassLoader()
.getResourceAsStream("upload/ctgryItem.xlsx");
```

If no one works but the required file exist in the webapps folder, you could load the file using

- `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`
- this will return: **/john/doe/tomcat/bin**
- use a simple algorithm to create the expected file location from the previous location:
- **/john/doe/tomcat/webapps/foo/bar/ctgryItem.xlsx**

## Explanation

The maven folder structure is just a help for developers:

[image]

The real internal structure of **jar** file is:

[image]

uncompressed sample jar: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/6.0.6

and this for **war**

[image]

sample war: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/

Answer (score 0):

you can try it :

```
InputStream inputStream= new ClassPathResource("static/resource/upload/ctgryItem.xlsx").getInputStream()
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
String outputFileName = new String(file.getName().getBytes("KSC5601"), "8859_1");
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + outputFileName + "\"");
        workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
```